# Case Based scenerio in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The DataFrame in pyspark looks like below.

```
model,DAYS

MarutiDesire,15
MarutiErtiga,30
Suzukicelerio,45
I10lxi,60
Verna,55
```

Output i am trying to get like

Output : I am trying to get the output as 
when days less than 30 than **economical**,

between 30 and 60 than **average**, 
and when greater than 60 than **Low Profit**

[image]

Code i tried but giving incorrect output.

```
dataset1.selectExpr("*", "CASE WHEN DAYS <=30 THEN 'ECONOMICAL' WHEN DAYS>30 AND LESS THEN 60 THEN 'AVERAGE' ELSE 'LOWPROFIT' END REASON").show()
```

kindly share your suggestion. is there any better way to do this in pyspark.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df.show()
+-------------+----+
|        model|DAYS|
+-------------+----+
| MarutiDesire|  15|
| MarutiErtiga|  30|
|Suzukicelerio|  45|
|       I10lxi|  60|
|        Verna|  55|
+-------------+----+

>>> df.withColumn("REMARKS", when(col("DAYS") < 30, lit("ECONOMICAL")).when((col("DAYS") >= 30) & (col("DAYS") < 60), lit("AVERAGE")).otherwise(lit("LOWPROFIT"))).show()
+-------------+----+----------+
|        model|DAYS|   REMARKS|
+-------------+----+----------+
| MarutiDesire|  15|ECONOMICAL|
| MarutiErtiga|  30|   AVERAGE|
|Suzukicelerio|  45|   AVERAGE|
|       I10lxi|  60| LOWPROFIT|
|        Verna|  55|   AVERAGE|
+-------------+----+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks Nikk, but getting error as NameError: name 'when' is not defined. unresolve reference 'lit'.

Comment: use  from pyspark.sql.functions import * top of your code

Comment: @OMG  I have added import in my answer use it.